# vim not finding the end of the sql statement

Tags: windows, vim

In `gvim` if I put the cursor (normal mode) in the word SELECT and then hit `\se` then it runs ok:

```
SELECT GETDATE();
```

If I do exactly the same but for a query over two lines then it errors.

```
SELECT 
GETDATE();
```

I have the lastest version of dbext installed.

Why ?

Comment: What do you expect `\se` to do? Also, since you appear to have a problem with a specific plugin, why don't you simply ask on the plugin's issue tracker or to the author directly rather than on this very generalist site?

Comment: morning romainl - I was expect `\se` to  execute the sql - works fine all on one line...but not once it is multi-line. I'll try the plugin's issue tracker - will this be on vim.org ?

Comment: No. Try the vim mailing list or contact the author directly, as per the plugin's description.

Comment: @romainl Thanks dude - I've posted to the vim-use Google Group : David has answered on there: I'll make sure vim plugin specific questions go on there first next time

Comment: Please note that I'm not trying to steer you away from SO/SU or even keep SO/SU clean or whatever. But problem solving is an important aspect of our craft and it's better to go from specific to generic than the reverse. Start with the doc, then the mailing list/forum/issue tracker, then google and SO/SU. Usually, problems are solved between step 1 and step 2 and it always make you learn more useful things in the process.

Comment: @romainl fair comment - I'm just on an initial period with vim at the moment where I'm trying to grab information from several sources: this period will end shortly and my learning will be structured more as you've outlined.